# keras SimpleRNN model data shape interpretation

Tags: python, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I have a very simple keras sequential model:

```py
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.SimpleRNN(1, input_shape=[None, 1], return_sequences=True),
])
model.compile(loss='mse')
```

My (toy) data looks like this:

```py
X = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6], [7,8]])[...,np.newaxis]
y = np.array([3,5,7,9])[..., np.newaxis]
```

X.shape -> (4,2,1)
y.shape -> (4,1)

Since I `return_sequences`, I expect my output shape to be `(4,2,1)`.
This is also what is returned from `model.predict(X)`.
My question: How is the loss computed in the fit, when the shape of the model prediction output mismatches the shape of `y`?
`keras.layers.mse(model.predict(X), y)` raises a shape mismatch..

The full code to experiment with:

```py
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6], [7,8]])[...,np.newaxis]
y = np.array([3,5,7,9])[..., np.newaxis]
print(X.shape)
print(y.shape)


model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.SimpleRNN(1, input_shape=[None, 1], return_sequences=True),
])

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model.summary()

model.fit(X, y, epochs = 1)
print(model.predict(X).shape)

# this fails as expected
# keras.losses.mse(model.predict(X), y)
```

versions: keras 2.2.4-tf with tensorflow 2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

You have set `return_sequences=False`

```
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.SimpleRNN(1, input_shape=[None, 1], return_sequences=False),
])
model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='sgd')
model.fit(X,y)
```

Comment: that was not my question, though. i was interested in why (and how) my code works. i expect it to fail

Comment: Are your sure ? It does fail for me as expceted `InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [4,2,1] vs. [4,1]
  [[{{node loss_5/simple_rnn_loss/SquaredDifference}}]]`

Comment: interesting, which tf/keras version? i am using tf 2.1.0 with keras 2.2.4-tf.
i am talking about the fit, right? because in the last line of my example, it fails for me, too

Comment: haa tf `1.14.0` and keras `2.2.4-tf`

Comment: so is this a feature or a bug? :D